# Parsing initial values to an ExtraSignUp Fields Meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, meteor-accounts

I am trying to add a hidden field for the user registration. The problem is not with the field itself but with its value. I want to parse it a default value. This is my code:

```
Accounts.ui.config({
    requestPermissions: {},
    extraSignupFields: [{
        fieldName: 'name',
        fieldLabel: 'Name',
        inputType: 'text',
        visible: true,
        validate: function(value, errorFunction) {
          if (!value) {
            errorFunction("Please write your first name");
            return false;
          } else {
            return true;
          }
        }
    },{
        fieldName: 'status',
        fieldLabel: 'Status',
        inputType: 'text',
        value: 'somevalue',
        visible: false,
    }]
});
```

> I want to add the value to the field 'status'.
>
> Actually, I found the answer. The option is the following code in the
>   server folder:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) { 
    if (options.profile) {
      user.profile = options.profile;
    }
     user.profile.status = "sth";
    return user; 
});
```

Comment: Are you using meteor-accounts-ui-bootstrap-3?

Comment: I am using  ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3. But the documentation is the same as meteor-accounts-ui-bootstrap-3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [the implementation of signup](https://github.com/ianmartorell/meteor-accounts-ui-bootstrap-3/blob/master/login_buttons_dropdown.js#L534) in that package, there is no way to set a default value.  The code just creates an object in `signup()` and grabs whatever existing values from the form that it can.

Comment: There is an option. Actually, it turns out that the developer has control over the package thanks to the Accounts.onCreateUser Function.